# Scene not updated without user interaction

Tags: python, pyqt5, vtk

I am trying to implement a simple visualization example using pyqt5 and vtk, while embedding the vtk objects `(vtkSphereSource)` in a `QFrame- (myFrame)`. My first problem is that the rendering is not updated, if I don't interact on the frame. The second is, if I do not set a fixed width and height for `widget`, the window is represented very small on the top left corner of my frame, although it has a `Expanding` size policy in the `ui` design. I would be thankful for any advice.

```
 # called first after the program start
 def initialize():
    global sphere
    sphere = list()

    global mapper
    mapper = list()

    global actor
    actor = list()

    global renderer
    renderer= vtk.vtkRenderer()

    self.widget = QVTKRenderWindowInteractor(self.myFrame)
    self.interactor = self.widget.GetRenderWindow().GetInteractor()
    self.interactor.SetInteractorStyle(vtkInteractorStyleTrackballCamera())

    renderer.ResetCamera()

    self.interactor.Initialize()

    self.widget.setFixedWidth(1000)
    self.widget.setFixedHeight(800)
    self.widget.GetRenderWindow().AddRenderer(renderer)

 # called later if new pos are avaialble
 def update_sphere_pos():

    array = np.array([[-3.40993, -145.858, 1062.88],
                       [2.9301, -240.421, 1037.68],
                       [3.36048, -252.239, 1014.06],
                       [-5.43725, -89.469, 989.953]])

    for idx in range(4):
        sphere.append(vtk.vtkSphereSource())
        sphere[idx].SetCenter(array[idx][0], array[idx][1], array[idx][2])
        sphere[idx].SetRadius(4)
        sphere[idx].Update()

        mapper.append(vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper())
        mapper[idx].SetInputConnection(sphere[idx].GetOutputPort())

        actor.append(vtk.vtkActor())
        actor[idx].SetMapper(mapper[idx])
        actor[idx].GetProperty().SetColor(0.0, 1.0, 0.0)

        renderer.AddActor(actor[idx])
        renderer.Modified()

if __name__ == "__main__":
  initialize()
  update_sphere_pos()
```

Comment: 1. Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example); 2. Avoid using globals at all costs, unless you **really** know what you're doing and why (and usually, when people uses them, it's because they don't know it).

Comment: I updated the question. But I can not put an ui file here.

Comment: Take a look into the VTK examples using Qt.

Comment: I am using already pyqt5+vtk embedding example here https://gist.github.com/paskino/7b7ed6e4541d682bd5ce5d521505dd8f